# Cursor isn’t changed properly when drag a file to a draggable view on Cocoa's WKWebView

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, wkwebview

I wrote the following code to put a draggable view on WKWebView.
With this code, I expected a "+" icon will be displayed nearby a cursor when I dragged a file to the view.

```swift
class ViewController: NSViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let rect = NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200)

        let webView = WKWebView(
            frame: rect,
            configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration())
        webView.load(URLRequest(
            url: URL(string: "https://i.imgur.com/D5ru3Q7.jpg")!))

        let draggableView = DraggableView(frame: rect)
        draggableView.registerForDraggedTypes([.fileURL])

        self.view.addSubview(webView)
        self.view.addSubview(draggableView)
    }
}

class DraggableView: NSView {
    override func draggingEntered(_ sender: NSDraggingInfo) -> NSDragOperation {
        return .copy
    }
}
```

The result is here:

[image]

- *Sometimes* the cursor changes to a magnifying glass (same as a mouse over behavior on WKWebView).
- And *sometimes* "+" icon is shown.

I think the `webView` prevents the cursor changing.
So I tried the followings. But I couldn't fix.

- Overriding `hitTest` of the webView worked only for non-dragging mouse over actions. But not for dragging.
- `webView.unregisterDraggedTypes()` didn't work.

Is there anyway to fix this?

Comment: Create a subclass of UIView and lay it under the web view control.

Comment: @ElTomato Thank you! According to your advice, I wrote this code: https://gist.github.com/mshibanami/b435e9794a6bfc9e721d3c2181531759 But the problem still persists. Probably I misunderstand what you said. Could you show me the details?

Comment: `WKWebView` already implements `NSDraggingDestination` so you can subclass `WKWebView` and override the `NSDraggingDestination` functions to provide your own logic.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution:

```swift
for t in webView.trackingAreas {
    webView.removeTrackingArea(t)
}
```

I think removing tracking areas on a web view is not a good idea.
But at least it satisfies my need.